# Why is my details page always passed the last item from a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React E-Commerce project, I list featured items. There are only 9 items in my database that have been marked as featured. I am also writing a Modal Details popup page if you click on any item. My featured items component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Card, Button, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText, CardGroup,
  CardSubtitle, CardBody, CardFooter, CardHeader, CardColumns, CardDeck
} from 'reactstrap';
import Config from 'config';
import { decompressToBase64, formatter } from './common.js'
import "./Item.css";
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import ItemModal from './itemModal.js'

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
    let scrollAmount = 0;
    var slideTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (direction === 'left') {
            element.scrollLeft -= step;
        } else {
            element.scrollLeft += step;
        }
        scrollAmount += step;
        if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
            window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
        }
    }, speed);
}

class FeaturedCards extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
            isOpen: false
        };        
    }    

    async componentDidMount() {
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
        const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

        buttonRight.onclick = function () {
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            sideScroll(container, 'right', 25, 300, 10);
        };

        buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            sideScroll(container, 'left', 25, 300, 10);
        };

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token
        });

        const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `/api/Items/GetFeaturedItems`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ itemList: json });
    }   

    render() {
        const items = this.state.itemList;
        const { isOpen } = this.state;

        let onRequestClose = () => {
            this.setState({ isOpen: false });
        }

        let handleClick = () => {
            console.log("Clicked")
            this.setState({ isOpen: true });
        }

        return (
            <span id="featItemsSpan">
                <Button id="slideLeft" color="primary">{String.fromCharCode(8249)}</Button>
                <CardGroup id="container" className="card-group-scroll">
                    {items && items.map(item =>
                        <>
                        <Card key={item.itemNumber} tag="a" onClick={handleClick} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                            <CardImg top className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + decompressToBase64(item.images[0]?.compressedImageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                            <CardBody className="card-body">
                                <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                                <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                                <CardText className="card-description">{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                            </CardBody>
                            <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                        </Card>
                            {isOpen ? <ItemModal item={item} onRequestClose={onRequestClose} /> : null}
                        </>
                    )}
                </CardGroup>
                <Button id="slideRight" color="primary">{String.fromCharCode(8250)}</Button>
                
            </span>
        );
    }
}
export default FeaturedCards;
```

My modal pops up when I click on an item, however the item passed to the modal is always the last item (9th in my case) in the list, regardless of what item I actually clicked on. I know this is my stupid mistake, but can I get a shove in the right direction to help me learn and fix it?

Comment: Not sure how do you pass the item but you should move the handleClick and onRequestClose function outside of the render method, remember to bind the functions when you do that.

Comment: You're not using React properly. Rule of thumb: when you find yourself using `document.getElementById()` you're doing it wrong. Re your problem: you're using a *single* state variable to keep track of the state of *nine* modals. They probably all appear on top of each other, which means only the last one is actually visible.

Comment: What is "frtom"?   I can't decide if that should be "from", if it should be "to", or if it intentionally means "from or to."

Comment: @ChrisG From your comment... I moved the `<ItemModal ...>` outside my `map()`. I am using the click handler to set the item and then call the Modal. You provided the direction I needed. Care to put this in an Answer so I can accept it?

Comment: That's okay, this is a duplicate for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you must move your Modal Component outside of map().

And on click saving active item to state.

Then pass this item to modal.

Now, by click on item 9 modals will be opened.

Comment: This is true but not an answer. This question is also a duplicate.